# Error: "using prover9/mace4 and symbols/arities are used as both relation and function symbols"

Tags: logic

I am trying to do some coursework that involves proving a real world scenario using prover9/mace4. I am getting this error:

> %%ERROR: The following symbols/arities are used as both relation and
>   function symbols: kissed/2.

Can someone explain what this means? I just want to understand, what the error means.

Comment: Perhaps you have wrote something like `all x (kissed(x,x) & kissed(x,x) = $T).` instead of `all x (kissed(x,x) & kissed(x,x) <-> $T). `.